# Spring AOP with AspectJ not intercepting

Tags: java, maven, aop, aspectj

I am writing my first AOP. I have pasted the code below which isnt getting intercepted on the method call.
I am not sure what could be the reason.

On the console it only prints:

addCustomerAround() is running, args : dummy

and none of the AOP advice code is printed.

Can somebody help?

**Interface:**

```
package com.test.model;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public interface AopInterface {


    @Autowired
    void addCustomerAround(String name);
}
```

**Class:**

```
package com.test.model;

import com.test.model.AopInterface;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Component
public class AopClass implements AopInterface {

    public void addCustomerAround(String name){
        System.out.println("addCustomerAround() is running, args : " + name);
    }
}
```

**AOP:**

```
package com.test.model;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;



@Aspect
public class TestAdvice{


     @Around("execution(* com.test.model.AopInterface.addCustomerAround(..))")
       public void testAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        System.out.println("testAdvice() is running!");
        System.out.println("hijacked method : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        System.out.println("hijacked arguments : " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));

        System.out.println("Around before is running!");
        joinPoint.proceed(); 
        System.out.println("Around after is running!");

        System.out.println("******");

       }
}
```

appcontext.xml:

```
<!-- Aspect -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <bean id="AopClass" class="com.test.model.AopClass" />
    <bean id="TestAdvice" class="com.test.model.TestAdvice" />
```

**POM:**

```
<!-- AOP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Method call:**

```
aoptest.addCustomerAround("dummy");
```

Comment: Where do you get the reference to your AopClass instance before doing the method call? Has it been wired by Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any error here. I've just tried your code and it works well.
My test class:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("appcontext.xml");

        //-------------------------
        AopClass aopClass = (AopClass) appContext.getBean("AopClass");
        aopClass.addCustomerAround("dummy");
    }
}
```

[image]
Result

Can you retry to build your maven project?! And try again?!

Comment: Did you make any changes to appcontext.xml ?

Comment: No, just had to re-build and it worked. Silly me :-/

Answer (score 1):

According to [Aspect Oriented Programming with Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html), when a class implements interface(s), a JDK dynamic proxy will be used and if no interface is implemented then a CGLIB proxy will be created. To force CGLIB proxy you have to set proxy-target-class="true".
appcontext.xml:

```
<!-- Aspect -->
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"></aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
<bean id="AopClass" class="com.test.model.AopClass" />
<bean id="TestAdvice" class="com.test.model.TestAdvice" />
```

Output :

```
testAdvice() is running!
hijacked method : addCustomerAround
hijacked arguments : [dummy]
Around before is running!
addCustomerAround() is running, args : dummy
Around after is running!
******
```